# firebase rules (rest of collections)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

assuming I have N collection, I need to apply rules to one or two of them...

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /collectionONE/{ondDoc} {
       allow write, read: if false
     }
     match /collectionTWO/{twoDoc} {
       allow write, read: if false
     }
     // all my other collections
     match /{document=**} { // BAD
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow write: if false;  
    }
  }
}
```

My last rule would overwrite the first time which I want to block.

My question is, what is the equivalent to `the rest of collections rules`... I mean, I dont want to do rules per each collection if they are the same if there any way to accomplish this?

Best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to accomplish this with the given security rules language.  You can't have a wildcard that matches everything *except* other things you've already defined.  Consider restructuring your data to support the way your rules need to work.